# How to save data in json file?

Tags: json, node.js, typescript, angular6

I need to save JSON data into a `.json` file after converting an object to a string using `JSON.stringify`

This is my current code:

```
const jsonObject: object = {
      'countryName': 'Switzerland',
      'users': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Basel',
          'founded': -200,
          'beautiful': true,
          'data': 123,
          'keywords': ['Rhine', 'River']
        },
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Zurich',
          'founded': 0,
          'beautiful': false,
          'data': 'no',
          'keywords': ['Limmat', 'Lake']
        }
      ]
    };

const myData = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

**Note: I want to save this data dynamically, and I was used to jsonConverter of jsonTypescript2.**

I tried using this method:-

```
let a = document.createElement('a');

// JSON.stringify(jsonObject), 'ex.json' // another
a.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(myData));
```

Comment: Try JSON.parse(myData)  inside the encodedURIComponent method.

Comment: Argument of type 'myData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: but if I use stringify(jsonObject) no error

Comment: After clicking the "a" element you want to save the data ?

Comment: yes save data in jsonfile

Comment: such as save data in assets/i18n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay after 6 days ago I discover best solution, how to connect between Angular 6 and Node.js + json File **directly and dynamically** .

```
npm install file-saver --save
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';


const jsonObject: object = {
      'City': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Basel',
          'founded': -200,
          'beautiful': true,
          'data': 123,
          'keywords': ['Rhine', 'River']
        },
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Zurich',
          'founded': 0,
          'beautiful': false,
          'data': 'no',
          'keywords': ['Limmat', 'Lake']
        }
      ]
    };


const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(jsonObject)], {type : 'application/json'});
saveAs(blob, 'abc.json');
```

Comment: would it be possible to over write an existing json file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fs.js` NPM module to write data to file

There are a lot of details in the [filesystem API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html). The most common way (as far as I know) is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/fileName.json", myData, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Comment: var fs = require('fs'); doesn't work in angular 6 :D .

Comment: same error : WARNING in 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'component'

Comment: If you want user to download this json data then need to create a download, if you want to save this json data into your server or machine where application is running then angular wont be able to do it.

Comment: need to install module, using npm i fs

Comment: I tried install npm i fs module but doesn't work in angular 6

Comment: what you want user to download json file in his system?

Comment: I use ngx-translate and I wanna write 2 data fr and en dynamically

Comment: use <textarea></textarea>

Comment: I can get data of HTML to Typescript but I can't save data in file.json

Comment: save data in assets/i18n/en.json and assets/i18n/fr.json